# QML conditional Binding not working as expected

Tags: qt, qml

If I have a simple `Binding` object of the form:

```
Rectangle {
    height: 400
    width: 500

    property var someObj: null

    Binding on color {
        when:  someObj
        value: someObj.color
    }
}
```

Then I would expect that when `someObj` is not `null`, `someObj`'s `color` property is bound to this object's `color` property.  What I actually get is a runtime error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of null
```

Any reason why this doesn't work?

Doing the *almost* equivalent JavaScript expression:

```
color: {
    if ( someObj != null ) {
        return someObj.color;
    } else {
        return "black";
    }
}
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Uhm...did you try to reduce to a minimum example to isolate the (possible) bug? if you could post that minimum example it would be interesting to check it out.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I've edited a minimal example into the question.

Comment: @Mitch There's already a bug report for this, quite an old one too: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22005

Comment: Yes, BUG indeed as guessed by @Mitch. It works if you set an id and use it to refer the `someObj`. Using the id to refer to the parent: very good. :/

Comment: just a simple `color: someObj? someObj.color: "black"` is pretty much enough here, btw (note that you don't need to instantiate `Binding` objects when you are "inside" of the item which properties you'd like to bind)

Comment: Perhaps you want to answer and accept this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [in the comment by BaCaRoZzo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579956/qml-conditional-binding-not-working-as-expected#comment45472120_28579956), the minimal example given in the question does not work because it gives a `ReferenceError: someObj is not defined`. However, after fixing this with an `id` for the `Rectangle`, then **the example actually works despite the TypeError**:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect

    height: 400
    width: 500

    property var someObj: null

    Binding on color {
        when:  rect.someObj
        value: rect.someObj.color
    }
}
```

This correctly sets the color as expected when `rect.someObj` is set and contains a `color` property.

The reason for the `TypeError` is that the expression `rect.someObj.color` is evaluated already when the `Binding` is created (see [QTBUG-22005](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22005)).
So to prevent the `TypeError`, one can simply check for `rect.someObj` to be set in the `value` expression of the `Binding`:

```
    Binding on color {
        when:  rect.someObj
        value: rect.someObj ? rect.someObj.color : undefined
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the following way:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    height: 400
    width: 500

    property var someObj

    color: someObj ? someObj.color : "black"

    Button {
        id: buttonTest
        text: "test"
        onClicked: parent.someObj = test
    }
    Button {
        id: buttonTest2
        anchors.left: buttonTest.right
        text: "test2"
        onClicked: parent.someObj = test2
    }

    QtObject {
        id: test
        property color color: "red"
    }

    QtObject {
        id: test2
        property color color: "blue"
    }
}
```

If `someObj` is undefined the color of the rectangle is black, if someObj is defined, the Value of the color property is chosen.

**Edit:** I've seen to late, that that's only what mlvljr suggested in the comments, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The `QML` syntax defines that curly braces on the right-hand-side of a property value initialization assignment denote a binding assignment. This can be confusing when initializing a `var` property, as empty curly braces in JavaScript can denote either an expression block or an empty object declaration. *If you wish to initialize a `var` property to an empty object value, you should wrap the curly braces in parentheses*.

For example:

```
Item {
    property var first:  {}   // nothing = undefined
    property var second: {{}} // empty expression block = undefined
    property var third:  ({}) // empty object
}
```

In the previous example, the first property is bound to an empty expression, whose result is `undefined`. The second property is bound to an expression which contains a single, empty expression block `("{}")`, which similarly has an `undefined` result. The third property is bound to an expression which is evaluated as an empty object declaration, and thus the property will be initialized with that empty object value.

Similarly, a colon in JavaScript can be either an object property value assignment, or a code label. Thus, *initializing a `var` property with an object declaration can also require parentheses*:

```
Item {
    property var first: { example: 'true' }    // example is interpreted as a label
    property var second: ({ example: 'true' }) // example is interpreted as a property
    property var third: { 'example': 'true' }  // example is interpreted as a property
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(first.example) // prints 'undefined', as "first" was assigned a string
        console.log(second.example) // prints 'true'
        console.log(third.example) // prints 'true'
    }
}
```

So the code should be as follow:

```
Rectangle {
    height: 400
    width: 500

    property var someObj: ({color: ''})

    Binding on color {
        when: someObj.color
        value: someObj.color
    }
}
```