# Qt5 - QML: How to modify bindings to change Text after ProgressBar finishes loop

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to operate a change of text after a `ProgressBar` finishes its loop as shown below.

The actual result I have is the following:

[image: wrong]

**The expected** result would be the one below:

[image: correct]

Below the code of the minimal verifiable example. I am handling the `ProgressBar` as an external `C++` class. 
In case needed the **small verifiable example** can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/textchange/src/master/) in case needed:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls.impl 2.12  // for IconLabel

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

//    property var changeText
//    color: changeText ? changeText.color : "green"

    function buttonClick(button)
    {
        button.text = qsTr(" YES Connecting").arg(button.text);
        button.enabled = false;
        if (button.background && button.background instanceof Rectangle) {
            button.background.color = "green";
            button.background.gradient = null;
            button.background.visible = true;
        }
        if (button.contentItem && button.contentItem instanceof IconLabel) {
            button.contentItem.color = "white";
            button.contentItem.font.bold = true;
            button.contentItem.font.pointSize = 20;
        }
    }
    function textConnectedChange(textChange1)
    {
        textChange1.text = qsTr("Connecting...");
        textChange1.color = "blue";
        textChange1.content = "Connected";
        textChange1.font.bold = true;
        textChange1.font.pointSize = 15;
    }

    QtObject {
            id: test
            property color color: "grey"
        }

    ColumnLayout {
        Button {
            id: dialogA
            text: pBar.running ? "Connecting..." : "Not - Connected"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.pointSize: 20
            spacing: 10
            onClicked: {
                buttonClick(this)
                pBar.startComputation()
            }
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            id: layout
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            spacing: 10
            GroupBox {
                id: box1
                width: parent.width
                title: "Connection"
                font.pointSize: 20
                Layout.fillWidth: parent
                spacing: 10

                GridLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    columns: 1
                    RowLayout {
                        id: row1
                        spacing: 200
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Label {
                            id: textField
                            text: "Connection:"
                            font.pointSize: 15
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                        }
                        Text {
                            id: connected
                            text: pBar.running ? textConnectedChange(this) : "Not-Connected"
                            color: "red"
                            font.pointSize: 15
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            onTextChanged: {
                                text: parent.changeText = test
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            GroupBox {
                id: boxprogress
                title: "Connection Progress"
                font.pointSize: 20
                Layout.fillWidth: parent
                width: parent.width
                spacing: 10
                GridLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    columns: 1
                    RowLayout {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        ProgressBar {
                            id: progressbar_id
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Layout.fillHeight: true
                            width: parent.width
                            from: 0
                            to: 40
                            value: pBar.progress
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**progressbar.h**

```
#ifndef PROGRESSBAR_H
#define PROGRESSBAR_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QFutureWatcher>
class ProgressBar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float progress READ progress NOTIFY progressChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool running READ running NOTIFY runningChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool finished READ finished NOTIFY finishedChanged)
public:
    ProgressBar();
    float progress();
    bool running();
    bool finished();

public Q_SLOTS:
    void startComputation();
    void cancelComputation();
    void finishComputation();
private Q_SLOTS:
    void updateProgress(int value);
signals:
    void progressChanged();
    void runningChanged();
    void finishedChanged();
private:
    bool m_running = false;
    int m_progressValue = 0;
    int m_finished = true;
    QVector<int> vector;
    QObject m_Model;
    QFutureWatcher<void> m_futureWatcher;
};

#endif // PROGRESSBAR_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "progressbar.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    ProgressBar pBar;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pBar",   &pBar);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**What  I have done so far:**

1) The following [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579956/qml-conditional-binding-not-working-as-expected) was useful in understanding the problem but didn't bring any beneficial correction.

**2)** this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437841/how-to-connect-a-qt-quick-button-click-to-a-c-method) I found to be useful in order to modify the necessary bindings to change a text but didn't work

**3)** I consulted the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) regarding the `QML` bindings and tried to apply directly from there but something is not correct.

**4)** You see `QObject` in the code and that is because from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579956/qml-conditional-binding-not-working-as-expected) I thought I had to use it. I left it in the code to show you what additional trials I was trying to do, but that didn't work.

Please point in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: You should consider storing the example on gist.github.com for better readability of your post, that's probably why you got a downvote

Comment: @Amfasis, thank you very much for reading the question. Yes I am actually about to put the link. Will do it in one sec.

Comment: The small verifiable example can be found here [https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/textchange/src/master/](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/textchange/src/master/)

Comment: I would also remove the cpp code in this case, as it is kinda easy to fill in the gaps, and if not, there is the bitbucket link. Or maybe leave the header

Comment: ok thank you I took out the header to make it simpler

Comment: Uhoh, I meant the other way around, show the header with the Q_PROPERTY but leave the cpp implementation to the bitbucket link

Comment: Ops sorry one sec...

Comment: Ok I have just updated the code in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML has a `State` object, which is perfectly suited for handling this kind of problem, I mean, you want different bindings in different "states".

The following example should get you quite somewhere, however, I'm not 100% I extracted everything correctly from your example:

```
Text {
    id: connected
    text: qsTr("Not-Connected")
    color: "red"
    font.pointSize: 15
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    states: [
        State {
            name: "connecting"
            when: pBar.running
            PropertyChanges {
                target: connected
                text: qsTr("Connecting...")
                color: "blue"
                font.bold: true
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "connected"
            when: pBar.finished
            PropertyChanges {
                target: connected
                text: qsTr("Yes! Connected...")
                color: "green"
                font.bold: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, however it still does not work because as soon as the `ProgressBar` finishes the loop, the text does not change.

Comment: I mean it changes during the progress (but this behavior was happening before). I am trying to understand how to change the text at the end of the loop of the `ProgressBar`. So that at the end of the computation, it says "Connected"

Comment: Ok, I added another `State`, but I don't see how you know you are connected, so I put `something.connected`, which you have to change for your own case

Comment: So basically inside the class `ProgressBar` there is a function called `void spinEC(int &iteration)` which is doing a random calculation (for which I am simulating a real wi-fi connection) and as soon as that finishes, the result should be `Connected`

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I just added an additional `Q_PROPERTY` on the `ProgressBar`. Where you referring to that?

Comment: Connected means the `ProgressBar` finished the computation

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I see you (now?) have the `finished` property, will update my answer for it

Comment: Thank Amfasis, I think using `State` is the solution. My `ProgressBar` does not work still. I think is because of the the property `finished` I added, and don't know why. But I am going to mark your answer as correct and write a separate question on how to correctly set a `ProgressBar`.  I must have make a mistake that I don't see. Thank you very much for your help! :)